# DesignAutomation V3 - Accesstoken

Tags: c#, authentication, forge, autodesk-designautomation

after changing the DesignAutomation to version 5.1.2 the login does not work anymore. I get as `isSuccessStatusCode` the value false back.

We register the Service with `AddDesignAutomation`, the URL to the token remains the same as the previous one (According to Github)
`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token`

However, I get back an unauthorized - IsSuccessStatusCode=false via the ResponseMessage.

We also tried in the admin area of autodesk to create a new app - with DesignAutomation V3, however I don't get this selection option of a V3 (see image).

What do I have to do that I can authenticate correctly again with version 5.1.2?

What have we tried (short summary):
New version included, registered the service and hoped that the authentication is then successful.  Unfortunately, no authentication is possible.

Comment: I just tested on sample code, I don't see any problem. Can you share the error screenshot.

Comment: i just tested the credentials with postman and get
`{
    "error": "invalid_credentials",
    "error_description": "The client credentials are invalid."
}`

Comment: OK, i created a new APP in Forge-Admin and use the new credentials, now it works fine.